# Why is an object sometimes null, when it gets initialized in a thread and accessed from main?

Tags: java, multithreading, object, null

When I create a new object in a thread which is an attribute of an object I´am giving to the thread it stays null in the main-function (but just without the System.out). I wrote a simple example of my Problem, which has the same result:

```
public class T1 {
    public T2 t2;
}
public class T2 {
    public String s;
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        T1 t1 = new T1();

        T3 thread = new T3(t1);
        thread.start();

        while(t1.t2 == null){
    //      System.out.println("null");
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

public class T3 extends Thread{
    public T1 t1;

    public T3(T1 t1){
        this.t1 = t1;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        t1.t2 = new T2();
        while(true){
            System.out.println(t1.t2);
        }
    }
}
```

So without `System.out.println("null")` it results in an infinite loop, but when I add this System.out it behaves like I suspect. I even get the same result or problem if I use static variables.

Is there some sort of optimization or something else I don´t understand? Or why is `t1.t2 always == null` without `System.out.println("null")`? I thought the T1-object and his attributes (in this case the object t2) will be created on the heap, which is shared between all threads and just the t1-reference-variable is stored on the stack. So hopefully someone can explain me, why it stays null without the `System.out`... The problem just occurs if the thread is executed after the while-loop, thats why there is a `sleep(1000)`.

Comment: See: [Loop doesn't see changed value without a print statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25425130/loop-doesnt-see-changed-value-without-a-print-statement)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> So without System.out.println("null") it results in an infinite loop, but when I add this System.out it behaves like I suspect. I even get the same result or problem if I use static variables.

If a thread is updating a value that another thread is reading, there must be some sort of memory synchronization.  When you add the `System.out.println(...)` this uses the underlying `PrintStream` which is a synchronized class.  So the call to `println(...)` is what synchronizes the memory between the threads.

Here's some good information around [memory synchronization from Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html).

You should add `volatile` to the `T2 t2;` field to have the updates to `t2` be visible between threads.

The real problem here is that with a modern multi-CPU (and core) hardware, each CPU has its own high speed memory caches.  Modern OS and JVM software makes use of these physical (and virtual) CPUs to schedule threads to run in parallel simultaneously.  These caches are a critical part of threading performance. If every read and every write had to go to central storage, your application would run 2+ times order of magnitude slower. The memory synchronization flushes the cache so that local writes getting written to central storage, and local cached reads are marked dirty so they have to be re-read from central storage when necessary.

Comment: Another good read: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility

Comment: thank you very much. So am I right, that my problem has to do with the happens-before relationship? Does the JVM re-orders the operations, so that the write (t1.t2 = new T2()) comes after all reads(while(t1.t2==null))? Or is it just optimizing the code with the assumption that since it never changes the value, it doesn't need to read it from memory? Or is it just always reading an old value? I tought that there is a global heap (or whatever) where all objects get read from.

Comment: No, not quite.  There _is_ a global heap but the problem is that the CPUs each have memory caches.  It's less about optimizations although that may contribute.  I've added some more to my answer @user2448967.

Comment: One essential remark I'm missing in this answer here is: _never do anything remotely like this in production code!_

Comment: Like what @iwein?  You mean use `System.out.println(...)` to synchronize?

Comment: @Gray yes, but that's just one thing, there are multiple problems in the code. To inverse the statement I'll say *always use final fields for sharing, if you have to mutate use Atomic** That covers it. Other strategies are going to eat up time and joie de vivre.

Comment: People share with volatile primitives all of the time.  If don't right this works well.  Just because it is `final` doesn't mean that there aren't non-final fields so I don't see what that saves @iwein.

Comment: @Gray `final AtomicBoolean flag = new AtomicBoolean(false);` saves about three fairies I think. Doing the sharing of volatile primitives right is possible but not worth the effort of documenting it every time. I'm not saying I don't like your answer by the way, I even voted for it, I think it would be better if it steered people away from the general idea :)